# iPhone SQLite commands with apostrophes

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sanitization

I'm writing an application for the iPhone that communicates with a SQLite database but I'm running into a small problem.  Whenever I try to query information based on a condition that contains an apostrophe, no results are returned.... even if a result that matches the requested condition exists.  Let me give some specifics...

### SQLite Table

---

Row--Column1--Column2---------

1. Test Data - 001
2. User's Data - 002

### Objective-C Code

---

```
//Create the sql statement
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

//Create the name of the category that will be passed in
NSString *categoryName = @"User's Data";

//Create the rest of the SQL query
NSString *sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM theTableName WHERE Column1 = ?";

//If there are no errors in the SQL query
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(theDatabase, sqlQuery, -1, &sqlStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Bind the category name to the sql statement
    sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, [categoryName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    //While there are rows being returned
    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        //Retrieve row data
    }
}
else
{
    //Save error message to the application log and terminate the app
    NSAssert1(0,@"Error: Failed to prepare the SQL statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
//Reset the sql statement
sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
```

I'm semi-new to objective C, so my first thought when writing this code was to sanitize the user inputs.  But after doing some research, I read that the sqlite3_bind calls do the necessary sanitation for you.  But whenever the code runs, the while loop is skipped right over because there are no rows being returned.  It *should* return the second row from the database table.  If I copy/paste the *exact* same SQL query into a SQL managing program (I use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)) (and with the necessary query sanitation of course), it returns the correct data.

I've spent a long time trying to debug this myself and even a greater amount of time trying to search online for a similar problem being explained and resolved, but to no avail.  As of now, I just disabled the user's ability to key in an apostrophe on the iPhone's virtual keyboard.  But this is a feature I'd love to include in my finished product.  Can anyone here offer me any helpful tips?  Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sqlite your request will be (as you can see it is even wrong highlighted):

```
SELECT * FROM theTableName WHERE Column1 = User's data
```

And it will wait for the closing ' symbol

You should echo ' symbol, for example in following way:

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Column1=\"%@\"", categoryName];
```

In this case query will be

```
select * from theTableName where column1="User's data"
```

that is completely legal query.

In this case you don't need binding any more and final code will look like:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlQuery UTF8String], -1, &sqlStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //While there are rows being returned
    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
       //Retrieve row data
    }
}
else
{
   //Save error message to the application log and terminate the app
    NSAssert1(0,@"Error: Failed to prepare the SQL statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Comment: I changed the select statement to your recommendation, but the same result occurred.  It frustrates me to no end that I can't observe the properties of the sqlite3_stmt while debugging.  I wish I could see what was going on beneath the hood.

Comment: Check the updated answer or you can use something like this:

    NSString *categoryName = @"User\'s data";

Comment: Rather then relying on the sql_bind statement, I put it directly into the char like you suggested and now it works perfectly!

First off, thank you so much for all of your help during this. But second off, out of curiosity, do you have any idea what sqlite_bind does?  Whatever it is doing seems to screw up my text input if it contains apostrophes, regardless of the formatting or wrapper I put around the character.

Comment: sqlite_bind_text sanitizes text to prevent SQL injections.
' and " are very often are used to create injection, so as I understand, it simply drops them, to avoid dropping you need to escape them like I proposed in alternative: NSString *categoryName = @"User\'s data". But that's easy if there is no a lot of operations or if using of such categories with apostrophes is hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

The official character is ''

sanitize with:

```
NSString *stringToSanitize = @"This is the value with ' character";

NSString *sanitized = [stringToSanitize stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                     withString:@"''"];
```

Then you can use it on your querys